# How do I extract the returned data from QDBusMessage in a Qt DBus call?

Tags: c++, dbus, qtdbus, qdbus

I'm trying to call WPA supplicant's DBus interface using Qt's QDBus
class library. In particular, I'm trying to use the "Get" property
call to retrieve the "Interfaces" property value.

The DBus specification (via introspection) for "Get" is:

```
<interface name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties">
    <method name="Get">
        <arg name="interface" type="s" direction="in"/>
        <arg name="propname" type="s" direction="in"/>
        <arg name="value" type="v" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    ...
</interface>
```

Seems simple enough. Two strings input and the output is a
variant (these are DBus types). For the "Interfaces" property I'm
expecting the variant to be an array of object paths (DBus type "ao").

I'm using `QDBusInterface::call()` to call the DBus method, which
returns a `QDBusMessage`, but I can't figure out how to extract my data
from this.

`QDBusMessage::arguments()` returns a `QList<QVariant>`. I've tried
various conversions of the items in this list in an attempt to find my
array of object paths, but I just seem to end up with an empty string
instead.

`QVariant::type()` seems like it should help, but it only seems to
return the type `QDBusMessage`, which is clearly wrong. For example:

```
// 'message' is of type QDBusMessage
qDebug() << "Argument 0 type is" << message.arguments().at(0).type();
```

prints:

```
Argument 0 type is QVariant::QDBusMessage
```

How do I extract the actual message data?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easiest way I've found is to use `qDebug()` to print results as you go. This usually points you to which type you need to convert to next, until you finally reach the innermost type.

**Qdbusviewer** is a useful tool for determining the DBus parameters that
will be required. In this case:

- WPAS Service: **"fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1"**
- WPAS Path: **"/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1"**
- Properties interface identifier: **"org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"**
- WPAS interface identifier: **"fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1"**

In initialising the `QDBusInterface` for calling `Get`, we need to use the
`Properties` interface, since that's the interface that provides the `Get`
method.

In calling `Get` using the `QDBusInterface::call()` method, the second and
third parameters correspond to the parameters listed in the
Introspection output (`"interface"` and `"propname"`). `"interface"` is
where the property can be found, which for the `"Interfaces"` property
is `"fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1"` (this can be confirmed using **qdbusviewer**).

The `"propname"` parameter is just the name of the property:
`"Interfaces"` in this case.

The code so far:

```
std::string getInterface()
{
    QDBusInterface interface( "fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1",
                              "/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1",
                              "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties",
                              QDBusConnection::systemBus() );

    // Calls DBus method
    QDBusMessage result = interface.call( "Get",
                                          "fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1",
                                          "Interfaces" );
```

This is the hard part. `QDBusInterface::call()` returns a `QDBusMessage`,
which has our property information trapped within.

```
    qDebug() << result;
```

This debug statement prints:

```
QDBusMessage(type=MethodReturn, service=":1.2431", signature="v", contents=([Variant: [ObjectPath: /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/7/Networks/0]]) )
```

Looks good. The "ObjectPath" is what we're after, and it's definitely in
there somewhere.

Next we need `QDBusMessage::arguments()`, which *"Returns the list of
arguments that are going to be sent or were received from D-Bus."* It
returns a `QList<QVariant>`.

```
    QList<QVariant> outArgs = result.arguments();
    qDebug() << outArgs;
```

The debug statement prints:

```
(QVariant(QDBusVariant, ) )
```

This 'notation' is a bit unclear (do brackets mean lists?), but we'll
keep going.

```
    QVariant first = outArgs.at(0);
    qDebug() << first;
```

prints:

```
QVariant(QDBusVariant, )
```

So the outer brackets do seem to indicate an array, though why there
is a comma used in the inner set and not in the outer set is a bit of
a mystery.

We keep converting types as we come across them:

```
    QDBusVariant dbvFirst = first.value<QDBusVariant>();
    //qDebug() << dbvFirst; // compile error!
```

`qDebug()` doesn't understand `QDBusVariant`, so no debug print is
available here. Instead if we look at the documentation for
`QDBusVariant`, we see that it provides a `variant()` method for
converting to a regular `QVariant` type.

```
    QVariant vFirst = dbvFirst.variant();
    qDebug() << vFirst;
```

We do seem to be going in circles, but the print output is a bit
different this time:

```
QVariant(QDBusArgument, )
```

Another conversion:

```
    QDBusArgument dbusArgs = vFirst.value<QDBusArgument>();
```

Unfortuately, `qDebug()` doesn't work here either. The `QDBusArgument`
type can hold a number of different element types, which are described
in the Qt documentation. `QDBusArgument::currentType()` tells you which
type you have. In our case:

```
    qDebug() << "QDBusArgument current type is" << dbusArgs.currentType();
```

prints:

```
QDBusArgument current type is 2
```

2 means `ArrayType`.

According to the `QDBusArgument` documentation, we can extract the
elements of the array using code like the following:

```
    QDBusObjectPath path;
    dbusArgs.beginArray();
    while (!dbusArgs.atEnd())
    {
        dbusArgs >> path;
        // append path to a vector here if you want to keep it
    }
    dbusArgs.endArray();
```

I've assumed the array element type is `QDBusObjectPath`, since at this point it makes
sense for it to be so. It'll be clear if I'm right.

If you get the error message `QDBusArgument: write from a read-only object`, change the declaration of `dbusArgs` to:

```
    const QDBusArgument &dbusArgs = vFirst.value<QDBusArgument>();
```

`qDebug()` doesn't support `QDBusObjectPath` either, but
`QDBusObjectPath::path()` returns a `QString`, so we can get our debug
print like this:

```
    qDebug() << path.path();
```

prints:

```
"/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/7"
```

At last!

Comment: Thanks @Zimano! It took me a long time to work it out at the time, so I decided to document it here.

Comment: The tip about declaring a `const QDBusArgument &` is very helpful when passing around complex variants on D-Bus.

Answer (score 1):

My goal was to get the object path returned by `GetInterface` method of `fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1` interface.

@MatthewD's answer was really helpful to get me started with the experiment but unfortunately didnt work for me as required. I tried all posibilities. But at the end, somehow, I got my required result in a different and a rather shorter way.

What I did was:
- I had the interface:
  `QDBusInterface interface("fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1", "/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1", "fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1", QDBusConnection::systemBus());`
- Call the method and store message
  `QDBusMessage mesg = interface.call("GetInterface", "wlan0");`
- Then get the first argument
  `QVariant var = mesg.arguments().at(0);`
- Then get the object path
  `QDBusObjectPath objpath = var.value<QDBusObjectPath>();`
- And finally
  `QString path_str = objpath.path();`

Now you print the path as string:
`printf("Object path: %s\n", path_str);`

Answer (score 0):

Well, after this long time!

I think after debugging the reply and seeing its `QDBusVariant` ...

the `variant()` methond of `QDBusVariant` result returns the QDBus Variant as `QVariant` object .. thus, the call :

```
const auto &resultArg = result.arguments().at(0).value<QDBusVariant>().variant();
```

return a `QVariant` .. that we could easily print in debug or convert to stored value in object.